# How to add text input variable to URL in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm having the weirdest problem right now. I have this JS code:

```
    function CreateChat() {
    var chatName = document.getElementById("chatName").value;
        window.location.href = "https://localhost:44321/CreateNewChat/CreateChat?ChatName=" + chatName;
}
```

Thing is, as it is, I can't make it work. It obviously should be calling a controller method, but it just won't work. If I hit that url with the project running and put anything at the end of it, like https://localhost:44321/CreateNewChat/CreateChat?ChatName=TestName, that test name variable will get to the controller without a problem. If I hardcode to the code the "TestName" instead of passing the chatName variable I define earlier, it will get to the controller, no problem. Hell, if I debug the script, the chatName variable gets loaded correctly with my input, and if I console.log the url it will show up correctly (in fact, I can copy/paste that url and it will hit the controller method correctly). But, as the code is presented above, it will never, by any means, hit the controller. It will reach that point, and cut the execution as if there was an error in the JS code. Do you guys have any ideas on this? It's driving me mad, really.

Just in case, this is how I define the text input in the HTML:

```
<input type="text" required class="form-control" id="chatName" aria-describedby="nameHelp" placeholder="Name your chat!">
```

Edit: encodeURIComponent on the chatName doesn't work either.

Comment: Also, no errors show up on the console.

Comment: Also 2: leaving the input empy will make it work (obviously, passing a null chat name to the controller method).

Comment: Have you checked if there are any requests happening through the Network tab in Dev Tools?

Comment: How do you call `CreateChat` function? Maybe the page is submitted differently before you change `windows.location`

Comment: Man, I got no clue. I copied your function and tried it locally; it worked. My only theory is that it's generating some strange, invalid URL and your browser doesn't wanna go there.

Also, a few tips here and there: Always use `encodeURIComponent` for when you're taking user input and putting it into a URL. Also consider changing your function's case to `createChat`, because that's more in line with the rest of JavaScript. But just my suggestions, not rules!

Comment: @DavidsKanal no request happens if I fill the text input, but I do get the expected request if I don't fill that field. I would assume it's a problem of the component or the way I'm setting up the URL, but I just can't make head or tails on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @HoomanBahreini this is the submit button that call the function: <button type="submit" onclick="CreateChat()" class="btn btn-primary">Create a New Chat!</button>

Comment: @DavidsKanal thanks man, I'll keep those in mind, I'm not too front/end savvy. I also have no clue; tried a different browser, same result. What drives me mad is that it only fails when I fill that text input, I'm going to change it to a generic one now and see if has something to do with that bootstrap component (not that that makes any sense whatsoever, but I'm really desperate over here)

Comment: @Postman No problem. Got it working now?

Answer (score 0):

try using `window.open` with `_self` instead:

```
window.open ('https://localhost:44321/yadayada','_self',false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a submit button (and I assume this button is inside a `form`)... when you click on the submit button the form is submitted to the submit action of the form, this is the default behavior for the submit action.

Now if you don't want your page to be submitted, you can change the button type to `button`:

```
<button type="button" onclick="CreateChat()" class="btn btn-primary">Create a New Chat!</button>
```

Alternatively if you actually need a `submit` button then you need to prevent the default behavior in order to change `window.location`:

```
function CreateChat(event) {
    e.preventDefault(); // <-- don't submit the form
    var chatName = document.getElementById("chatName").value;
        window.location.href = "https://localhost:44321/CreateNewChat/CreateChat?ChatName=" + chatName;
}
```

You need to pass the `event` to `CreateChat` function:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="CreateChat(event)" class="btn btn-primary">Create a New Chat!</button>
```